# What is the correct driver to use for a Samsung CLP365W printer?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I cannot get my new Samsung CLP365W printer to print via either wired (USB printer cable) or Wireless. Wireless printing works in 'doze Vista.

I have tried installing the drivers Ubuntu recommended for it from the driver database. When I did this and tried to print a test page, it said it was doing, the printer status said "Processing-Connected to Printer" and then changed back to "Idle" without printing anything out.

I have just carried out a version of the driver installing instructions from the Samsung Website and done something in the terminal about `sudo ./install.sh`, after moving the files into the home folder. Install got as far as the following error message:

```
./noarch/worker.sh: 310: ./noarch/worker.sh: Illegal number: 09
**** Install finished
```

What does that mean please?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by this way:

1. sudo su
2. (enter password)
3. ./uninstall.sh
4. ./install.sh

As I understood, any changes made by previous installation attempts, were disturbing to a new one.

Answer (score -1):

try removing the usblp module with:

```
rmmod usblp
```

and then run

```
./install.sh
```